SQL How do I aggregate across multiple columns where any match?
SQL Server 2012, everything needs to be a SELECT statement with no procedures (platform limitations).
I have a table like:
| Field A | Field B | Number Field | Row Num |
----------------------------------------------
| A1      | X       | 19           | 1       |
| B1      |         | 20           | 2       |
|         | X       | 23           | 3       |
| A1      |         | 45           | 4       |
|         | Y       | 13           | 5       |
| C1      | Z       | 23           | 6       |
| C2      | Z       | 24           | 7       |
|         | Z       | 12           | 8       |
| C2      |         | 4            | 9       |
| C2      | J       | 3            | 10      |
| C4      | J       | 6            | 11      |
| C1      | J       | 5            | 12      | 

And I want a result like:
| Field A | Field B | Number Field Sum |
----------------------------------------
| A1      | X       | 87 (rows 1, 3, 4)
| B1      |         | 20 (row 2)
|         | Y       | 13 (row 5)
| C1      | Z       | 77 (rows 6-12)

For rows 6-7, I don't care which combination of Field A and Field B is in the result set, only that all of the rows that are associated to each other are aggregated together.
I only need the sum or any other aggregate function, I don't need text that says '(rows 6-12)', that was just for explanation purposes.

The first issue is how to define the groups, for instance is this the total set of data, or are there more records. So is only A1 groupable with X and blank values for Field B? What happens if there was an A1 and Z? When there is a blank value for [Field A], does the number field aggregate in the A1 Z and or C1 Z group?
We need ot define the relationship between the fields, then the query is a matter of syntax

Hold up, so you are grouping by the first character of [Field A] only? That is much simpler, and then Field B is not only irrelevant but misleading in the results.

@ChrisSchaller no it's matching on the entirety of Field A. No, this isn't the total set of data. The various C and Z values show how they'd all be summed.

You should explain why C2 doesn't have a result row and why C1 in the results isn't C2, also Where is J. If you are making arbitrary rules, then you should probably explain them, the data alone does not sufficiently cover all cases.

Sounds like it's doing a "graph matching" thing where values that are somehow connected are all grouped together. This has been answered a gazillion of times before, just check the duplicates

@siggemannen thanks, I didn't know what the term to search for was.

You should include a branch diagram to show the relationship, also talk about precedence, is Field A the primary source, or Field B?

You should edit the post to clarify these questions before it attracts too much negative attention

This solution satisfies the request but makes 2 general assumptions that may not prove true for a larger data set:

Results are grouped primarily based on the first character of Field A

this is how C1 can match all the variants of C in the example (rows 6,7,9-12) and why we don't care about values for Field B = J


If Field A is missing a value in the row, then the value for Field A comes from looking up the first row with the same Field B value that does have a value for Field A

Also note that CTEs are used in this case to highlight the transformations
WITH FieldAFixed as (
  SELECT 
      COALESCE(results.[Field A], FieldALookup.[Field A]) as [Field A]
    , [Field B]
    , [Number Field]
    , [Row Num]
  FROM results
  OUTER APPLY (
               SELECT TOP 1 lkp.[Field A] FROM results lkp
               WHERE lkp.[Field B] = results.[Field B]
              ) FieldALookup
)
, Totals as (
  SELECT
    LEFT(ISNULL([Field A],' '),1) as [FieldGroup]
   ,SUM([Number Field]) AS [Number Field Sum]
FROM
    FieldAFixed
GROUP BY
    LEFT(ISNULL([Field A],' '),1)
)
SELECT [Field A], [Field B], [Number Field Sum]
FROM
    Totals
CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT TOP 1 [Field A], [Field B], [Row Num] 
             FROM FieldAFixed
             WHERE LEFT(ISNULL([Field A], ' '),1) = Totals.[FieldGroup]
            ) as FirstResult
ORDER BY 
    FirstResult.[Row Num];




Field A
Field B
Number Field Sum




A1
X
87


B1

20



Y
13


C1
Z
77




no it's matching on the entirety of Field A.

If the assumptions are not correct, then we need to better explain how the groups are formed, specifically in the example the values for C1, C2, C4, Z, and J rows, they don't all match 'C1' entirely, only partially.

This is a good example of a question that needs both example data and results as well as instructions. From the limited data alone all we can do is make a set of assumptions based on what is presented



To verify this, I used the following create table script:
CREATE TABLE Results (
  [Field A] char(2),
  [Field B] char(1),
  [Number Field] int,
  [Row Num] int
);
INSERT INTO Results ([Field A],[Field B],[Number Field],[Row Num])
VALUES
('A1','X',19,1),
('B1',null, 20 , 2 ),
(null,'X', 23 , 3 ),
('A1',null, 45 , 4 ),
(null,'Y', 13 , 5 ),
('C1','Z', 23 , 6 ),
('C2','Z', 24 , 7 ),
(null,'Z', 12 , 8 ),
('C2',null,  4 , 9 ),
('C2','J', 3  , 10),
('C4','J', 6  , 11),
('C1','J', 5  , 12);

The results of FieldAFixed are:



Field A
Field B
Number Field
Row Num




A1
X
19
1


B1
NULL
20
2


A1
X
23
3


A1
NULL

45 4


NULL
Y
13
5


C1
Z
23
6


C2
Z
24
7


C1
Z
12
8


C2
NULL

4  9


C2
J
3
10


C4
J
6
11


C1
J
5
12



And the results of Totals is:



FieldGroup
Number Field Sum





13


A
87


B
20


C
77




Unfortunately there's no character-relation between values. I thought I explained the matching rules, as another commenter said, it's Graph Matching.

So what determines the "top" of the hierarchy? Are you saying that just the row number? Also are the branches unique, so now that X is associated with A1 will it ever be associated with C1, and if it can, how does that affect the totals. We can do this with recursive CTEs but you need to be clear on the constraints

I don't care which is the top, just so long as something is. And yes, X could be associated with both A1 and C1, the total would be the sum of all records.

So it wouldn't matter that the sum of the sums could total more than the sum of all the individual records? In SQL we can't really go with I don't care what order when something must come first. Are you suggesting you would accept C4 J as the parent record for 6-12? If it is conceptually arbitrary then why are we showing Field B at all in the results? Or for that matter why Field A. When we specify logic like this we need to be specific or you might not like the results that you get

You can try the following query:
select fieldA, max(fieldB),sum(total_sum) total_sum
FROM
(
SELECT  max(fielda) fieldA,fieldB, sum(amount) total_sum
from temptable 
where fieldb ! = '' 
group by  fieldB
UNION
SELECT  fieldA, min(fieldB), sum(amount) total_sum
from temptable 
where fieldb = '' 
group by  fieldA
) tmp
group by fieldA

Checkout the dbFiddle as well.
